# Laravel: Change Blade Parser {{ }} to Custom Parser?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have plain text containing URL markup like this:

```php
$string = "This is a good \[example\]\(http://www.example.com\) for my problem."
```

Now I would like to pass this variable `$string` to a Blade template and parse it like this:

```html
This is a good <a href='http://www.example.com'>example</a> for my problem.
```

However, since `{{ }}` uses htmspecialchars the output looks like that:

```
This is a good &lt ;a href='http://www.example.com'&gt ;example&lt ;/a&gt ; for my problem.
```

At the moment, I parse the string with a custom function in a controller to the wanted output and present it in a Blade template with `{! $parsed_string !}`. Is there a way to change the default behavior of the function `{{}}` in Laravel?

Comment: use {!! !!} instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `{!! $yourVariable !!}` will let you output html elements.

From laravel docs:

> **Displaying Unescaped Data**
>
> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`

Answer (score 0):

If You do not want to escape any special character inside {{ }}, you can use
{!!....Your HTML code....!!}